# How to return custom value from a GUIDE GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How do I return a custom value from a GUIDE GUI instead of the figure handle?

`value = myGui();`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the GUI you want (user controls, entry fields, processing logic, etc)
2. Modify the default GUIDE-generated code as follows (intentionally left out anything with no need to modify).

`uiwait` as last line in `OpeningFcn()`

```
function myGui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

... % anything else you may want to do 

% Wait here until user completes gui calculation.
% Without pausing execution here, by default the figure handle 
% would be immediately returned to the calling code.
uiwait();
```

Note: this *will block execution* in your calling code.

Package output value and call `uiresume()` in desired callback.

```
function btnReturnValue_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)

...

calcValue = doSomeCalculations();

% Set 'output' value which will be returned from this figure.
handles.output = calcValue;

% Update the 'guidata' so the handles.output value just set will be saved.
guidata(hObject, handles);

% Resume execution which was blocked by OpeningFcn().
uiresume();
```

Call the gui from some other code and store the resulting value.

`value = myGui();`

The returned value can be any matlab object (user class, struct, cell, etc).